# Make first option of select unselectable through arrow keys in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a select with options and when a user selects an option, it is removed from the select and displayed as a button. When the button is pressed, the option goes back to my select. Everything works fine with mouse click, but if we navigate with the arrows key, the user can select my first option which is "choose fruit". How do I make it unselectable? disabled="disabled" doesn't work. Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gbjcw1wp/2/. To reproduce the problem, select a fruit, then press Up arrow key on your keyboard.

EDIT : ONLY HAPPENS IN GOOGLE CHROME.

Disabling arrow keys work, but i'd like another way of accomplishing this.

HTML:

```
<select id="combobox" onchange="cbchange();">
    <option selected="selected">Choose Fruit</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="pear">pear</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
</select>
    <br>
    <br>
 <div id="buttons"></div>
```

Javascript :

```
var fieldnames = [];
var valuenames = [];  
function sortComboBox() {
    document.getElementById("combobox").remove(0);
    var my_options = $("#combobox option");
    my_options.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.text.toUpperCase() > b.text.toUpperCase()) return 1;
        if (a.text.toUpperCase() < b.text.toUpperCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
    });
    $("#combobox").empty().append('<option>Choose Fruit</option>').append(my_options);
    $('#combobox option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
}  
function cbchange() {
    var index = $('#combobox').get(0).selectedIndex;
    var text = $('#combobox option:selected').text();
    var selectedItem = $('#combobox').val();
    $('#buttons').append('<table class="ui"><tr><td class="variable">' + text + '</td><td class="icon"><span id="' + selectedItem + '" class="icon ui" value="X" onclick="addOption(\'' + text + '\',this.id)">X</span></td></tr></table>');
    $('#combobox option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
    fieldnames.push(text);
    valuenames.push(selectedItem);
}
function addOption(text, selectedItem) {
    for (var i = valuenames.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (valuenames[i] === selectedItem) {
            valuenames.splice(i, 1);
            fieldnames.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    $("#combobox").append($("<option></option>").val(selectedItem).text(text));
    $('#' + selectedItem).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
    sortComboBox();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple change to your code can resolve your problem.

Give the default option some weird value. Eg:

```
<option value="null" selected="selected">Choose Fruit</option>
```

And append the follow code the the start of your cbchange() function.

```
if($('#combobox').val()=="null"){
        return false;
    }
```

See [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mmf8tjva/1/)